# jQuery casting Objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, casting, jhtmlarea

i have a jQuery Object but need it to be a jHtmlArea Object. jHtmlArea is derived from jQuery so it should work theoreticaly - but i haven't found anything on this topic.

I know i can cast from javaScript Object to jQuery and back but not how to cast to a specific object.

---

**UPDATE:**

Found [this](http://jsenki.blogspot.com/2007/10/better-way-to-cast-object-to-primitive.html) very usefull and now made it work with a workaround for jHtmlArea at least. 
See the solution [here](http://jhtmlarea.codeplex.com/discussions/75317).

Comment: jHtmlArea is a jQuery plugin, which means that it would have to open itself an interface to grab the data as an object to work. If you have experience working with jQuery plugins you could probably root through the jHtmlArea source to see if there is an underlying object and, if so, if it's exposed to the outside world.

Answer (score 1):

You have read

http://pietschsoft.com/post/2009/07/21/jHtmlArea-The-all-NEW-HTML-WYSIWYG-Editor-for-jQuery.aspx

Right?

It should be as easy as

```
$("#myTextBox").htmlarea();
```

BTW, there is no custom object-element type for an htmlarea-ized jQuery object. You simply manipulate them with `.htmlarea({/*My parameters here*/}`

Comment: This is not, by the way, casting of one Javascript type to another, as the OP thought.

Comment: It is possible that this is not even what the OP intended to do with the object. A little more context from him would be super helpful.

Comment: Right. It is not what i wanted. This will not give me the jHtmlArea methods outside the jHtmlArea object.